# Error: "corSymm" objects must be a sequence of consecutive integers when running this code

Tags: self-study, lme4-nlme, generalized-least-squares, error-message

The Applied Longitudinal Analysis, 2nd Edition book as an R code to replicate table in section 5.7. The data for the TLC trial (tlc.dta) can be downloaded here:https://content.sph.harvard.edu/fitzmaur/ala2e/tlc.dta

The code reproduced here from the site above is as follows:

```
ds <-read.dta(tlc) #reading data from local source

ds$baseline <- ds$y0
tlclong <- reshape(ds, idvar="id", varying=c("y0","y1","y4","y6"), 
                     v.names="y", timevar="time", time=1:4, direction="long")
tlclong <- subset(tlclong, time > 1)


attach(tlclong)

week <- time
week[time==2] <- 1
week[time==3] <- 4
week[time==4] <- 6
time <- time - 1

week.f <- factor(week, c(1,4,6))

model <- gls(y ~ I(week.f==1) + I(week.f==4) + I(week.f==6) + I(week.f==1 & trt=="Succimer") + I(week.f==4 & trt=="Succimer") + 
                 I(week.f==6 & trt=="Succimer"), corr=corSymm(, form= ~ time | id), weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | week.f) )
```

R returns this error:

```
  unique values of the covariate  for "corSymm" objects must be a sequence of consecutive integers
```

Hoping someone can provide some insight into what is going on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a copy of Applied Longitudinal Analysis to check the results against, but I was able to fit this model by specifying the model formula differently:

```r
model <- gls(y ~ week.f * trt,
             corr = corSymm(form = ~ time | id),
             weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | week.f)
             )
summary(model)
```

```
# Generalized least squares fit by REML
#   Model: y ~ week.f * trt 
#   Data: NULL 
#        AIC      BIC    logLik
#   1893.523 1937.726 -934.7614

# Correlation Structure: General
#  Formula: ~time | id 
#  Parameter estimate(s):
#  Correlation: 
#   1     2    
# 2 0.775      
# 3 0.582 0.581
# Variance function:
#  Structure: Different standard deviations per stratum
#  Formula: ~1 | week.f 
#  Parameter estimates:
#        1        4        6 
# 1.000000 1.033619 1.150041 

# Coefficients:
#                       Value Std.Error   t-value p-value
# (Intercept)          24.660 0.9417630 26.184932  0.0000
# week.f4              -0.590 0.6427020 -0.917999  0.3594
# week.f6              -1.014 0.9343062 -1.085297  0.2787
# trtSuccimer         -11.138 1.3318540 -8.362779  0.0000
# week.f4:trtSuccimer   2.582 0.9089179  2.840740  0.0048
# week.f6:trtSuccimer   8.254 1.3213085  6.246838  0.0000

#  Correlation: 
#                     (Intr) wek.f4 wek.f6 trtScc wk.4:S
# week.f4             -0.291                            
# week.f6             -0.333  0.325                     
# trtSuccimer         -0.707  0.206  0.236              
# week.f4:trtSuccimer  0.206 -0.707 -0.230 -0.291       
# week.f6:trtSuccimer  0.236 -0.230 -0.707 -0.333  0.325

# Standardized residuals:
#        Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
# -2.1756413 -0.6507406 -0.1515546  0.5065705  5.6327463 

# Residual standard error: 6.65927 
# Degrees of freedom: 300 total; 294 residual
```